Artin's Example of the Orbit Stabilizer Theorem Applied to a Dodecahedron
I came across the following passage in Artin's Algebra (Section 6.10 page 181).

For example, let $F$ be the set of 12 faces of the dodecahedron, and let $H$ be the stabilizer of a particular face $f$, a cyclic group of order 5. The order of any $H$-orbit is either 1 or 5. So when we partition the set $F$ of 12 faces into $H$ orbits, we must find two orbits of order 1 and two orbits of order 5. The orbits of order 1 are those that fix the chosen face and the one exactly opposite of it.

How do we know that the order of any $H$ orbit is either 1 or 5? Does this have to do with the restrictions on the subgroups of a cyclic group of prime order? This result is fairly easy to visualize, but I wonder how to make it rigorous.

Yes, it's because $1$ and $5$ are the only divisors of $5$.
Choose any face $f'$, not necessarily the face $f$ that defines the subgroup $H$ in the first place. The Orbit–Stabilizer theorem establishes a natural bijection between the orbit $H \cdot f'$ and the cosets of its stabilizer $H/H_{f'}$. By Lagrange's theorem, the stabilizer $H_{f'} \leq H$ must have order dividing $|H| = 5$.
Now, the orbits under $H$ partition the set of $12$ faces, so their sizes must sum to $12$. These sizes are either $1$ or $5$ by the previous argument, so we have an integer partition of $12$ consisting of $1$s and $5$s. Since we have the singleton orbit $H\cdot f$ already, the possibilities are
$$
\begin{aligned}
12 &= 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 \\
12 &= 5 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 \\
12 &= 5 + 5 + 1 + 1
\end{aligned}
$$
It turns out by looking more closely at the particular action that we are in fact dealing with the last option.

Consider an orbit $X$.
The set $S$ of elements fixing some item $x$ in the orbit $X$ will be a subgroup of the group of order 5, hence have an order dividing 5. If the order of $S$ is $1$, then each of the five element of $H$ moves $x$ to someplace different, so the orbit $X$ has at least $5$ elements. But as $H$ has only five elements, $X$ can have at most five elements.
